# Shoot and intentionally miss

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose you are a guard at a prison, watching the surrounding scene from your observation tower. You have a gun and you are instructed to shoot any escapee you witness.

One day, you indeed witness a prisoner trying to escape from the prison. Though you will be punished if you do not act as instructed, you decide not to kill the prisoner.

So you shoot but intentionally miss. Is there a word for intentionally missing with a gun?

Comment: Common sense...?

Comment: In the UK at least, prison guards aren't armed anyway. But we do have (some) armed police. The general principle is they're not allowed to draw a weapon unless they expect to use it, and if they *do* shoot, they must shoot to kill. As it says in Wikipedia, [shooting to wound is generally viewed with skepticism by law enforcement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_to_wound). Any officer who could be *proven* to have deliberately shot to wound probably be *very* harshly treated by the legal system, but I don't recall it ever happening (or at least, ever making it to court in public).

Comment: "After all, he had hit that blasted highwayman with a single shot, from an awkward position in a carriage. Thoughts of that episode sent a shudder down his back. He would (now) most definitely **aim to miss**. Miss wide." http://books.google.com/books?id=ybhMRKuvXncC&pg=PT231&dq="aim+to+miss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Shoot to miss*** is the best I can think of.

If the notion needs to encompass both (a) intentionally aiming away from the person and (b) actually shooting, then this is about as succinct as it gets, I think.

(*Aim to miss* misses the fact of actually shooting, which he did in this case.)

Answer (score 17):

Aim to miss:

> This strikes me as pacifist hopeful thinking -- when it comes to "kill or be killed", do people really deliberately *aim to miss*?

Comment: "Our financial 'investigations' aim to miss."

Comment: Why do you think the only alternative to killing is being killed? And why should the only alternative to being killed be killing?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek - It's merely a quote to show the existence and use of the term. Shall I link it for you so that you can raise your objections there?

Answer (score 17):

The guard might have fired a [warning shot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warning_shot), if the intention was to scare or intimidate the (non-)target.  Whether it constituted a warning shot depends on whether there was an intention to follow up with other enforcement measures.

Comment: I think this is the best *general* answer for "intentionally missing with a gun," but it would not work in the context OP requested (i.e. deceptively disobeying orders to kill the prisoner), because one generally hears "warning shot" as an official command ('Lieutenant, fire a warning shot across their bow!')

Comment: I understand the question as "shoot to miss while still plausibly looking like shooting to kill", which is quite different from a warning shot, i.e., still in the general direction of the target instead of a completely safe direction.

Comment: @Peteris Warning shots are generally still quite near the target, to make sure that the target is aware of the warning and your ability to shoot on target. This usage seems fine for the context.

Answer (score 9):

Consider *spare*

> [spare](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare): choose not to punish or harm (someone)

Answer (score 5):

In the context of a formal duel, the correct term is [delope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delope).

Answer (score 2):

You can *aim high, or low,  or wide, or ahead of, or behind*.

The use of *aim* here implies intent rather than just a mistake.
you might also use *decided to deliberately aim ...*  to emphasize the deliberate nature of the miss even more:

> The guard decided to deliberately aim just behind the escaping prisoner.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also that some terms for actions such as this have both an accidental and intentional aspect to them. While it's not entirely appropriate to the action being discussed you could consider a term like *muffed*.

One can say muff a shot in say basketball or football either intentionally or unintentionally. The difference is usually inferred from context.

Answer (score 1):

In colonial Australia, to *aim high*; as opposed to *aim low*, meaning shoot to kill.